# Activity.saveInstanceState and Guava ImmutableList Serialization

Tags: java, android, guava

My activity has a member variable `private List<MyType> test` which is initialized to `ImmutableList.of()`. The only other assignment of this variable is `ImmutableList.copyOf()` which copies a `SingletonImmutableList` with a single element of `MyType`.

This is running on my android activity and I'd like to persist the value of this list.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (!test.isEmpty())
    {
        outState.putSerializable(SAVE_TEST_KEY, (Serializable) test);
    }
}
```

I have hooked the debugger up and on the line with `putSerializable(...)` , I can see that test is indeed a `SingletonImmutableList`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(SAVE_TEST_KEY))
        {
            Object tTest = savedInstanceState.get(SAVE_TEST_KEY);
        }
    }

  ...
  }
```

On the line `savedInstanceState.get(...)` I can see that the result of the get is an `ArrayList`. Trying to cast this to an ImmutableList predictably leads to a ClassCastException.

Can someone explain why the type would change from serialization to deserialization?

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I would have ever found that. Thanks for the link!

Comment: You're welcome! I just happened to remember some keywords of that question, so it wasn't *too* hard to find :-)